# Error while building squish for crosscompile ARM on ubuntu

Tags: linux, g++, armv7, squish

when i am trying to build SQUISH on ubuntu for armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi with QT5 , i was getting below error

```
Checking Qt library path
> /opt/timesys/nitrogen6x/toolchain/opt/qt5/lib
? Checking whether Qt is built with thread support
: Looking for /opt/timesys/nitrogen6x/toolchain/opt/qt5/lib/libqt-mt.so
: Looking for /opt/timesys/nitrogen6x/toolchain/opt/qt5/lib/libqt-mt.so
: Looking for /opt/timesys/nitrogen6x/toolchain/opt/qt5/lib/libqte-mt.so
: Looking for /opt/timesys/nitrogen6x/toolchain/opt/qt5/lib/libqte.so
: findQtHelper: soversion: 4, debug false, framework false
: findQtHelper: No QtCore at /opt/timesys/nitrogen6x/toolchain/opt/qt5/lib/libQtCore.so.4
: findQtHelper: soversion: 4, debug true, framework false
: findQtHelper: No QtCore at /opt/timesys/nitrogen6x/toolchain/opt/qt5/lib/libQtCore_debug.so.4
: No suitable Qt libraries found
# No Qt library found in /opt/timesys/nitrogen6x/toolchain/opt/qt5
```

below is the command i used,

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/timesys/nitrogen6x/toolchain/bin


sudo ./configure --disable-all --enable-server --enable-wrappers --disable-tk --with-qtdir=/opt/timesys/nitrogen6x/toolchain/opt/qt5/ --with-qmake=/opt/qt5/bin/qmake --host =armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi
```

please tel me how i can resolve these error?

Thanks Brijesh

Answer (score 0):

Have you built against Qt3.3 already?  Looks like it may be looking for that...remember you have to do the silly "double-build"...unless Froglogic has changed the rules for Qt5.

Otherwise, run sudo apt-get install libqt3-mt and point to those libraries during first half of compilation.